# How to display Dropbox Folders after logging in

Tags: ipad, api, sdk, dropbox

I am in the process of learning the Dropbox SDK.  I want to learn how to display the users Dropbox folders as well as give the user the option to upload the file from my app to their Dropbox account.

I have looked through their example app but it is not giving me the info that I need.

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might find this tutorial useful.
http://www.nanaimostudio.com/blog/2011/1/20/how-to-synchronize-your-app-data-using-dropbox-api.html

You can call upload method on the DBRestClient object.

```
    NSString* path = [self getDocumentPath];//or however you can obtain the path where your file is stored
   [restClientObject uploadFile:@"filename" toPath:@"/" fromPath:path]; 
   //you can choose to upload to the dropbox root directory(above) or a folder of your choice eg toPath:@"/myfolder"
```

Use loadMetaData for displaying the contents of dropbox folder

```
 [restClientObject loadMetadata:@""];
```

you also have to implement `loadedMetadata`function. Refer the tutorial above.

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)restClient:(DBRestClient *)client loadedMetadata:(DBMetadata *)metadata{

    NSMutableArray *list=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (DBMetadata *child in metadata.contents) {
        [list addObject:child];
    }
    self.arrayFoldersList=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:list];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
    [self.restClient loadMetadata:@""];
```

I think this will help you alot.